# Shell script to check for a file at regular period

Tags: bash, shell, unix, ssh

I am new to Shell Script. Please help.

A process is creating a trigger file at a particular location. I want to check whether that file is yet created or not. So i am writing a shell script that can be scheduled to run at 15 mins before estimated end time of the process.

```
        function go()
        {

            ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $SSH_User_IP      
            scp $PMROOT/NACO/SrcFiles/SDS/sds/sds_interface_core.trg $SSH_User_IP:$PMROOT_Fload/td_import/interface/sds/sds_interface_core.trg
            sleep 3                                                                                     
        }
        while true 
        do 
            go 
        done
```

The location where i have to check is on another unix machine on which i have to do ssh. So the help which i need is in putting things together so that my script can connect through ssh and check for a trigger file every 1 mins.

Answer (score 0):

Ssh returns the exit code of the remote command. This should work:

```
while true; do
    ssh username@remotehost "[ -e /path/to/file/to/check ]"
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "file exists!"
        break
    fi
    sleep 60
done
```

Hannu

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
while true; do
    ssh hostname "test -f /some/file" && { echo "file exists"; break; }
    sleep 60
done
```